# TypeScript compile error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

Installed Visual Studio 2015, added a TypeScript file to an existing project folder. File looks like this (from a Telerik sample):

```
interface Book {
    title: string;
    author: string;
    bookInfo: () => string;
}

var b: Book = {
    title: 'Moby Dick',
    author: 'Herman Melville',
    bookInfo: function () {
        return this.title + " by : " + this.author;
    }
}

var book = b.bookInfo();
alert(book);
```

Upon building the solution, I got an error:

Severity: Error
Description: Automation server can't create object
Project: Project1
File: VSTSC

Went into Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 and ran tsc just to see what comes back:

> C:\Tfs\Project1\Scripts\app>tsc 
>   tsc.js(703, 13) JavaScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object

Same message as the one in Visual Studio 2015.

Unsure what is the problem with the TypeScript compiler. I did make sure I installed TypeScript 1.5.4 via Tools > Extensions and Updates.

What shall my next step be?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as one of well known issue. Consider [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323885)

Comment: Yes, I looked there before and per link, it only supports Windows 2000 and XP. Am running Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: I have no idea... try to compile your code with [**gulp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) or something like this. Also try to post your problem on [official  github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new)

Answer (score 1):

The default tsc on windows (non node version) uses IE's JavaScript engine to execute the JavaScript.

[From here:](http://www.jakeludington.com/ask_jake/20111022_how_to_fix_error_automation_server_cant_create_object.html)

> The simple solution may be to reset your IE security settings to the default Medium-high setting

Also disable any third party active x components you installed in IE.

Comment: that doesn't work for me, i also tried to change it in many ways